# Grep regexp for matching ip addresses in a file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I'm trying to search a file "Sessions" that contains IP addresses (among other useless junk). My Grep is failing to match, even though [REGEXR](http://regexr.com/) is matching perfectly all the IPs perfectly ... so I know the REGEX is correct ... but when I GREP for this same pattern, not is returned.

```
for i in $(grep --regexp=[0-9]{1,3}[\.][0-9]{1,3}[\.][0-9]{1,3}[\.][0-9]{1,3} sessions); do echo $i; done
```

I've tried a variation of ways on that GREP (without the long options)

```
for i in $(grep '^[0-9]{1,3}[\.][0-9]{1,3}[\.][0-9]{1,3}[\.][0-9]{1,3}$' sessions); do echo $i; done

for i in $(grep "[0-9]{1,3}[\.][0-9]{1,3}[\.][0-9]{1,3}[\.][0-9]{1,3}" sessions); do echo $i; done
```

I don't understand. I've read the man page and also tried egrep as well. Here is a sample of what I'm searching ...

```
SEGMENT=#109#0%111.111.111.111%22%USER%%-1%-1% %%22%%0%-1%Interactive shell%
SEGMENT=#109#0%222.222.222.222%22%USER%%-1%-1% %%22%%0%-1%Interactive shell%
SEGMENT=#109#0%333.333.333.333%22%USER%%-1%-1% %%22%%0%-1%Interactive shell%
SEGMENT=#109#0%444.444.444.444%22%USER%%-1%-1% %%22%%0%-1%Interactive shell%
SEGMENT=#109#0%555.555.555.555%22%USER%%-1%-1% %%22%%0%-1%Interactive shell%
```

Comment: The  `^` and `$` character "anchor" a search to the first and last character of each line. Meaning that, for your 2nd example regexs, a line can only contain an IP address, but your sample data all shows `SEGMENT=#109#0%` at the "front" of the line (and other at the end). Not sure why your `--regex...` version isn't working. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't escaping your `{` and `}` with `\` as you should, also you probably want to use `-o` for "**o**nly show match"

```
grep -o --regexp="[0-9]\{1,3\}[\.][0-9]\{1,3\}[\.][0-9]\{1,3\}[\.][0-9]\{1,3\}" sessions
```

Comment: An alternative for your exact file format in `awk` is `awk -F'%'  '{print $2}' sessions`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, you need to escape `{` and `}`.

Alternatively, given your input format, this is in my opinion simpler and easier to read:

```
awk -F'%' '{ print $2 }' sessions
```

It works by splitting each line around the `%` character and selecting the 2nd field.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
egrep '0*([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.0*([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.0*([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.0*([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])' sessions
```

to ensure that ip-like entries won't match my regexp.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was not escaping the curly braces, thanks @Victory! Once I did that, it all worked.  Additionally, splitting the fields by "%" also worked remarkably well, again, thanks @Filipe Goncalves